# Some questions in the Category theory.

Tags: category-theory

I have two simple questions about the category theory.

1. In any category, is $Hom(A, B)$ always nonempty? In some typical categories, it seems right but the definition of morphism does not give any information.
2. In the category $\textbf{Set}$ of all sets, what is in $Hom(\varnothing, A)$ and $Hom(A, \varnothing)$?

Please anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be empty, and the a relation on some empty set is empty, so there is an empty function.

Comment: $\hom_{\mathsf{Ring}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hom(A,B) can be empty.  For example, the category with only two objects and only identity morphisms is a perfectly valid category.  For a more "natural" example, the path groupoid of a space with two different path components will have no morphisms from any object in one component to the other component. (Actually the first example is a specialization of the second to the discrete space with two points)

In Set, Hom($\emptyset,A$) consist of a single morphism for each $A$, the empty function.  $\emptyset$ is the initial object in the category of sets.

Hom($A,\emptyset$) is always empty unless $A = \emptyset$, in which case it has only the identity morphism.

Comment: why $Hom(A, \emptyset )$ is empty?

Comment: If $A$ is non-empty, what are its elements going to map to?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine There's a relation (take the cartesian product), right? But this relation is a function.

Comment: @user40276 You mean take $A \times \emptyset$ and consider the projection $A \times \emptyset \to \emptyset$ ? Well, take a good look at what is $A \times \emptyset$.

Comment: @Pece No, I'm trying to say that the relation is the cartesian product and that it's a function (thinking using set theory).

Comment: @user40276 A (binary) relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$ and is not necessarily the graph of a function. Be more explicit.

Comment: @Pece Ok, what's a relation? A set of ordered doubles. So $A \times \emptyset $ is a relation, but if $(x, y) = (x', y)$, then $x = x'$ since there is no $y$, therefore it's a function.

Comment: @user40276: indeed it is a function; but it is not a function with domain $A$!

Comment: @MaliceVidrine but if the domain is not $A$, then the codomain in the morphisms of $Hom(\emptyset, A)$ is not $A$ too. Am I missing something?

Comment: A function $f:A \to B$ is by definition a subset of $f \subset A\times B$ such that for all  $a \in A$ there is a unique $b \in B$ so that $(a,b) \in f$.  There can be no function from $A \to \emptyset$ if $A$ is non empty, because there are no $b \in \emptyset$ to pair with a given $a \in A$.  However, there is a function from $\emptyset \to A$ because the universal quantifier is vacuously satisfied:  there are no $a \in \emptyset$ to place any conditions on the relation.

Comment: Codomains and domains aren't symmetric in this way. Every value of the empty function is in A vacuously; that's enough for it to be the codomain. But a function must map every element in its domain *somewhere*.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I can understand your point, but defining the function  $A \times \emptyset $ the domain is the first variable in each double which is  an element of $A$ since $A \times \emptyset = \{ \{ a, \{a \} \}; a \in A\}$.

Comment: $A\times\emptyset =\emptyset$.

Comment: Actually $A \times \emptyset = \emptyset$.  I think, in many ways, it is a little confusing the track down all the set theoretical technicalities.  In the end, you want a category where $\emptyset$ is the initial object and singleton sets are the final objects.  You also want these to be distinct.  Following your categorical nose from there leads to the correct notions.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Actually an ordered pair $(a, b) = \{ a, \{ a, b \} \}$ but since there is no $b$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Sorry for being stubborn, but so the set theory does not match with the categorical notion?

Comment: If $\{a,\{a\}\}$ were in $A\times\emptyset$ you would have a contradiction; $\{a,\{a\}\}=\langle a,a\rangle$, which would imply that $a\in\emptyset$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine there is no contradiction. $A \times \emptyset = \emptyset $ in the category (as a product), but not in the set theoretical sense.

Comment: Also, in any Cartesian closed category $A\times 0\cong 0$, so it's not just a quirk of $\mathbf{Set}$ either.

Comment: In the set-theoretical sense the product is, indeed, empty.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Sorry for my insistence, but why do you think so? What's your definition of ordered tuple and cartesian product?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Sorry but I need to clarify myself. $A \times B = \{ \{ a  \{  a, b \}  \} ; a \in A \wedge b \in B  \} $ so $A \times \emptyset $ is not empty in the set theoretical sense at all. Note that my definition is different from Steven Gubkin definition of function.

Comment: By the definition you give, it **would be empty** for the reason I stated--$\{a,\{a\}\}=\{a,\{a,a\}\}$. Furthermore, you can see this is wrong categorically: if there's a function $1\to 0$ then *every* object would be initial and terminal since $Set$ is cartesian closed.

Comment: Suppose there is an $(x,y)\in A\times\emptyset$ then $y\in\emptyset$, which is a contradiction, since the empty set is indeed empty.

Comment: @user40276 Perhaps this will help convince you. It is true for all finite sets that if $|A|=n$ and $|B|=m$ then $|A\times B|=nm$ where $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. It follows that $|A\times\emptyset|=0$ for all finite sets $A$ and we know that the only set with zero elements is the empty set. Hence $A\times\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Comment: If $A \times B = \{ \{a,\{a,b\}\}: a \in A$ and $b\in B \}$, then $A \times B$ is empty, because there are no $b \in B$ to form any ordered pairs with!

Comment: $(a,)$ does not mean anything.  $\{a\}$ does equal $\{a,a\}$ because a set is determined by its elements.

Comment: It doesn't contradict regularity. It's part of the definition of $\{a,a\}$. $\{a,a\}=\{x:x=a\vee x=a\}=\{x: x=a\}=\{a\}$. And you can pick at the ordered pairs all you want, it still doesn't change the consequence of believing there's a function $1\to 0$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine you're right, $a = a$, I'm getting retarded, but since there is no assumption about existence in the definition of the cartesian product $A \times \emptyset = A \times A$ and there is such function.

Comment: Only if $A=\emptyset$. I have been talking about $A$ nonempty this whole time. So yes, there's an arrow $\emptyset\to\emptyset$; but it's the *only* arrow with codomain $\emptyset$.

Comment: Note that $a\in\{\langle x,y\rangle:x\in X\wedge y\in Y\}$ abbreviates $\exists b(a\in b\wedge\forall z(z\in b\iff\exists x,y,w(x\in X\wedge y\in Y\wedge w=\{x,y\}\wedge z=\{x,w\})))$. So there definitely are existence demands on members of $X$ and $Y$.